# count words in input field from datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I chose the calendar days using the datepicker. Marking days on the calendar - the date is written in the INPUT, separated by commas like this:

```
<input type="text" id="altField" value="2015-09-25, 2015-09-26">
```

It works, but I want also display number of selected days. With lenght I decided to count the number of words that are in input like days.

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function dayCount( val ){
    return {
        days              : val.match(/\S+/g).length
    }
}
var $div = $('#result');
$('#altField').on('input', function(){
  var c = dayCount( this.value );
  $div.html(
      "<br>Days: "+ c.days
  );
});
</script>
```

But it is not working. If I input words byth keyboard or copy paste them i  to input field script counts them, but if values comes from calendar script doesnt count them. What shoul i change?

Comment: Why not just split the value on , and count the number of items in the resulting array?

Comment: can you show any example?

Comment: Sorry, don't think it will help.  I thought the problem was counting the dates.  But you say the problem is that you are not catching the event when a new date is selected in the date selector.
What calendar script are you using?